# Why can't I assign a value from a pandas dataframe in my function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe called fresp, and in command line I can do this:

```
for i in range(0,len(fresp)):
    num=fresp.at[i,'caseid']
```

And that works just fine. The exact same code, when saved in a .py file, gives me:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

specifically in reference to num=fresp.at[i,'caseid'].

Here is the whole function. When I save it in a .py file, import the function, and run it, I get the error. When I just copy the whole thing into command line (minus then first def line), it runs just fine. Why would this be?

```
def ValidatePregs(df,fresp):
    pregmap=MakePregMap(df)
    counter=0
    for i in range(0,len(fresp)):
        case=fresp.at[i,'caseid']
        num=fresp.at[i,'pregnum']
        if num == 0 and case in pregmap:
            print("Mismatch for "+case+".")
            counter +=1
        elif num != len(pregmap[case]):
            print("Mismatch for "+case+".")
            counter +=1
    if counter==0:
        print("No mismatches!")
```

(I'm reading/doing Think Stats 2.0.35 by Allen B. Downey. I'm working on Exercise 1. I know there's a more elegant solution, but I still want to know why this does/doesn't work.)

Comment: How are you calling the function `ValidatePregs`, and what are the first few lines of your data?

Answer (score 1):

I think I know your problem:
In these lines:

```
num=fresp.at[i,'pregnum']
if num == 0 and case in pregmap:
```

You try to fetch a row using `at` which is similar to `loc` and returns a `pd.Series` object. When you do the comparison, Python is comparing the `pd.Series` which has an ambiguous truth value.

To avoid this, you can use `iloc` to fetch the row, and then access the `pregnum` value:

```
num = fresp.iloc[i].pregnum
if num ...
```